# Publish same message to different queues in RabbitMQ using Masstransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

any body can help me finding how can I send the message to differents queues (depending on business logic) to differents queues in RabbitMQ, using Masstransit

I have read the documentation I didn't found how I can specify the queue destination name
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [read the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#send) again. If you want to send to a specific queue, you actually have to send to the exchange for that queue created by MassTransit.

Use the `ISendEndpointProvider` (or `ConsumeContext`):

Call `await GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("exchange:name"))` or `await GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:name"))` to get the `ISendEndpoint`.

Call `Send(...)` to send the message to the exchange or queue.

Comment: really apreciate your help